# Azure tables : how to manage class versions

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I am trying to get started with using Azure tables. I learnt that Azure tables store objects of a particular class. Could you please tell me how the table accomodates versioining of classes?

Suppose there is a class A with property p1 to start with and say we have stored objects o1 and o2 of type A into a table T. Lets say later we add another property p2 to A. Now, what kind of behavior would we get when we use the new definition of A to retrieve o1 and o2? Will it throw some error? If not, what would be the value of p2 for thee objects when retrieved?

Or is the developer responsible for managing different class definitions in his application?

Answer (score 4):

Very important note: Don't think of Azure Tables as an `object store`! Think of it as a `key-value store` with **non-fixed** schema.

Going for you particular example. When you store `o1` and `o2` from `class A`, you will have 2 rows in your table:

- PartitionKey_1, RowKey_1, p1_1
- PartitionKey_2, RowKey_2, p1_2

Then you add new property to that class and store the object. The result will be a third row:

- PartitionKey_3, RowKey_3, p_3, p2_1

Later you can retrieve all the data you need and map it to an instance of a class that has property names corresponding to the table columns!

If you try to fetch the first two records into the latest class A, you will simply get a `NULL` (or default value for value types) for the `p2` property.

If you try to fetch row 3 into earlier class A, you will only get the `p1` property value. (Eventually you may see an error, but not a crucial one, you will still be able to map P1 column from the table to the P1 property of your object).

As a reference [Understanding Table Service data model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179338.aspx) is very good starting point for you.

As you just begin, I also suggest that you go through the [Windows Azure Storage Client library 2.0 - Tables Deep Dive](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2012/11/06/windows-azure-storage-client-library-2-0-tables-deep-dive.aspx). This article describes in very details how to save and fetch data from Azure tables.

Comment: Great answer, Additionally the 2.0.x clients expose a DynamicTableEntity object that can be used to query without a specific class type and simply access properties as a dictionary. This can be helpful when querying for data where type information is unknown.

Answer (score 0):

Precisely, when you retrieve the first three objects, they will simply come out without p2. If you are using the default deserialization methods of class TableEntity, your objects will have p2 as null.